# Prevent CSS-Sheet from loading in Wordpress Backend

Tags: css, wordpress

A Plugin i use in Wordpress has a css stylesheet which I only need in the frontend but not in the wordpress backend. (There it causes a small bug)

How can I prevent the stylesheet from loading in the backend?
Or the other way around, how can I make a stylsheet load only in the frontend?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

With [Simple Custom CSS and JS plugin by SilkyPress.com](https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-css-js/) the CSS can be set to appear In Frontend, In Admin or On Login Page separately.

Answer (score 0):

Check slug of imported style and use this solution

```
// this will remove the stylesheet when init fires
add_action('admin_init','your_remove_default_stylesheets');

// this is your function to deregister the default admin stylesheet
function your_remove_default_stylesheets() {
    wp_deregister_style('wp-admin');
}
```

Change `wp-admin` to your slug
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_deregister_style/